# Re-training inception google cloud stuck at global step 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am following the flowers tutorials for re-training inception on google cloud ml. I can run the tutorial, train, predict, just fine.

I then substituted the flowers dataset for a test dataset of my own. Optical character recognition of image digits.

[image]

My full code is [here](https://github.com/bw4sz/MeerkatReader/blob/master/cloudML/MeerkatReader.sh)

Dict File for [labels](https://github.com/bw4sz/MeerkatReader/blob/master/cloudML/dict.txt)

Eval [set](https://github.com/bw4sz/MeerkatReader/blob/master/cloudML/testing_data.csv)

Training [Set](https://github.com/bw4sz/MeerkatReader/blob/master/cloudML/training_data.csv)

Running from recent docker build provided by google.

```
`docker run -it -p "127.0.0.1:8080:8080" --entrypoint=/bin/bash  gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local-20161227
```

I can preprocess files, and submit the training job using

```
  # Submit training job.
gcloud beta ml jobs submit training "$JOB_ID" \
  --module-name trainer.task \
  --package-path trainer \
  --staging-bucket "$BUCKET" \
  --region us-central1 \
  -- \
  --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/training" \
  --eval_data_paths "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval*" \
  --train_data_paths "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/train*"
```

but it never makes it past global step 0. The flowers tutorial trained in about ~ 1 hr on the free tier. I have let my training go as long as 11 hrs. No movement.

[image]

Looking over at stackdriver, nothing progresses.

[image]

I have also tried a tiny toy dataset of 20 training images, and 10 eval images. Same issue.

The GCS Bucket ends up looking like this
[image]

Perhaps unsurprisingly, I can't visualize this log in tensorboard, nothing to show.

Full training log:

```
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:00 +0000       unknown_task            Validating job requirements...
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:01 +0000       unknown_task            Job creation request has been successfully validated.
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:01 +0000       unknown_task            Job MeerkatReader_MeerkatReader_20170110_170701 is queued.
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:07 +0000       unknown_task            Waiting for job to be provisioned.
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:07 +0000       unknown_task            Waiting for TensorFlow to start.
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:10 +0000       master-replica-0                Running task with arguments: --cluster={"master": ["master-d4f6-0:2222"]} --task={"type": "master", "index": 0} --job={
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:10 +0000       master-replica-0                  "package_uris": ["gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/MeerkatReader_MeerkatReader_20170110_170701/f78d90a60f615a2d108d06557818eb4f82ffa94a/trainer-0.1.tar.gz"],
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:10 +0000       master-replica-0                  "python_module": "trainer.task",
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:10 +0000       master-replica-0                  "args": ["--output_path", "gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/MeerkatReader/MeerkatReader_MeerkatReader_20170110_170701/training", "--eval_data_paths", "gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/MeerkatReader/MeerkatReader_MeerkatReader_20170110_170701/preproc/eval*", "--train_data_paths", "gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/MeerkatReader/MeerkatReader_MeerkatReader_20170110_170701/preproc/train*"],
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:10 +0000       master-replica-0                  "region": "us-central1"
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:10 +0000       master-replica-0                } --beta
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:10 +0000       master-replica-0                Downloading the package: gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/MeerkatReader_MeerkatReader_20170110_170701/f78d90a60f615a2d108d06557818eb4f82ffa94a/trainer-0.1.tar.gz
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:10 +0000       master-replica-0                Running command: gsutil -q cp gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/MeerkatReader_MeerkatReader_20170110_170701/f78d90a60f615a2d108d06557818eb4f82ffa94a/trainer-0.1.tar.gz trainer-0.1.tar.gz
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:12 +0000       master-replica-0                Building wheels for collected packages: trainer
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:12 +0000       master-replica-0                creating '/tmp/tmpSgdSzOpip-wheel-/trainer-0.1-cp27-none-any.whl' and adding '.' to it
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:12 +0000       master-replica-0                adding 'trainer/model.py'
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:12 +0000       master-replica-0                adding 'trainer/util.py'
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:12 +0000       master-replica-0                adding 'trainer/preprocess.py'
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:12 +0000       master-replica-0                adding 'trainer/task.py'
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:12 +0000       master-replica-0                adding 'trainer-0.1.dist-info/metadata.json'
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:12 +0000       master-replica-0                adding 'trainer-0.1.dist-info/WHEEL'
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:12 +0000       master-replica-0                adding 'trainer-0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:12 +0000       master-replica-0                  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for trainer: finished with status 'done'
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:12 +0000       master-replica-0                  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e8/0c/c7/b77d64796dbbac82503870c4881d606fa27e63942e07c75f0e
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:12 +0000       master-replica-0                Successfully built trainer
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:13 +0000       master-replica-0                Running command: python -m trainer.task --output_path gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/MeerkatReader/MeerkatReader_MeerkatReader_20170110_170701/training --eval_data_paths gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/MeerkatReader/MeerkatReader_MeerkatReader_20170110_170701/preproc/eval* --train_data_paths gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/MeerkatReader/MeerkatReader_MeerkatReader_20170110_170701/preproc/train*
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:14 +0000       master-replica-0                Starting master/0
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:14 +0000       master-replica-0                Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job master -> {0 -> localhost:2222}
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:14 +0000       master-replica-0                Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222
ERROR   2017-01-10 17:22:16 +0000       master-replica-0                device_filters: "/job:ps"
INFO    2017-01-10 17:22:19 +0000       master-replica-0                global_step/sec: 0
```

Just repeating the last line until I kill it.

Is my mental model for this service incorrect? All suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks fine. My suspicion is that there is a problem with your data. Specifically I suspect TF is unable to read any data from your GCS files (are they empty?)? As a result when you invoke train, TF ends up blocking trying to read a batch of data which it can't do.

I would suggest adding logging statements around the call to session.run in [Trainer.run_training](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/flowers/trainer/task.py#L226). This will tell you whether that is the line where it is getting stuck.

I'd also suggest checking the sizes of your GCS files.

TensorFlow also has an experimental [RunOptions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a304537954a865752ad1b18461e6bd67b36082db/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L251) which allows you to specify a timeout for Session.run. Once this feature is ready, this might be useful for ensuring code doesn't block forever.

Comment: The GCS files are 'empty', they exist but are only 20 bytes, compared to ~20-50kb per .gz for the flowers tutorial. It is not clear to me what makes preprocess.py fail (perhaps I should open a new question with correct tags).

Comment: Confirmed. For future reference, this is what happens if the path is wrong in the eval.csv. I had an extra slash in the  bucket name.